# How to write Python code that makes one column csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have my 500000 numerical values txt file.Couple of lines

```
  -938.549927    
  -938.542419    
  -938.534912    
  -938.523621    
  -938.523621    
  -938.512329    
  -938.512329    
  -938.523621    
  -938.519836    
  -938.523621    
  -938.519836    
  -938.508606    
  -938.508606    
  -938.508606    
  -938.519836    
  -938.531128    
  -938.538635
```

I want so save it as csv file.I have tried this

```
import csv

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('d500.txt')]

myfile = open('n500.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(lines)
```

I got this

```
wc -l n500.csv
1 n500.csv
```

Just part of the file

```
358337    ","  -938.362061    ","  -938.369568    ","  -938.369568    ","  -938.369568    ","  -938.380859    ","  -938.377075    ","  -938.380859    ","  -938.373352    ","  -938.347046    ","  -938.343262    ","  -938.339539    ","  -938.324524    ","  -938.313232    ","  -938.328247    ","  -938.320740    ","  -938.320740    ","  -938.328247    ","  -938.324524    ","  -938.324524    ","  -938.316956
```

What I really want is something like this

```
 -938.316956   
 -938.316956   
 -938.313232
```

If I try

```
wr.writerows(lines)
```

format is crazy

```
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","3","2","3","2"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","2","8","2","4","7"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","2","0","7","4","0"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","2","0","7","4","0"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","2","8","2","4","7"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","2","4","5","2","4"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","2","4","5","2","4"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","6","9","5","6"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","3","2","3","2"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","3","2","3","2"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","0","9","4","4","8"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","6","9","5","6"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","6","9","5","6"," "," "," "," "
" "," ","-","9","3","8",".","3","1","3","2","3","2"," "," "," "," "
```

My new code version

```
import csv

lines = [[line.rstrip('\n')] for line in open('d500.txt')]

myfile = open('n500.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerows(lines)
```

Than I got

```
"  -938.324524    "
"  -938.313232    "
"  -938.328247    "
"  -938.320740    "
"  -938.320740    "
"  -938.328247    "
"  -938.324524    "
"  -938.324524    "
"  -938.316956    "
"  -938.313232    "
"  -938.313232    "
"  -938.309448    "
"  -938.316956    "
"  -938.316956    "
"  -938.313232    "
```

How to get rid of quotation marks?

Comment: You have failed to show what `d500.txt` looks like.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Please take a look now!

Comment: `writerow` does as the name says, it writes a row. So your list of values is interpreted as one row.

Comment: @ppasler So what should I do?

Comment: use `writerows` instead

Comment: @MotaF try writerows instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

Comment: @ppasler take a look at my edit,creates havoc!

Comment: my bad, string is interpreted as sequence... you can try adding `[]` around `line.rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: @ppasler Almost perfect,I still have quotation marks problem.

Comment: When you ask for quoting `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`  you get quoting.

Comment: Handle quotes like this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL

Comment: @ppasler Thanks,but works perfect laso when I delete quote all.

Comment: What is the difference between the content of your input and output file?

Comment: @MikeMüller Only format,content is the same.

Comment: And what is the difference in the format?

Comment: I am on Linux,csv can be used on Windows also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is rename your .txt to .csv (or copy to a .csv file).

Since there is only one column, no (**c**omma) **s**eperators are needed.

Comment: Since OP is working on Ubuntu and Windows the line breaks matter.

Comment: @ppasler They really shouldn't matter. Any decent parser should be able to handle both forms. If not, all open data on the net would need to have two versions (some are with crlf, others with lf only).

Comment: indeed it shouldn't matter, just thought, as he uses `rstrip` explicitly to remove line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `writeline` inside the loop

```
import csv

with open('n500.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    [wr.writerow(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open('d500.txt')]
```

The `with` statement handle file closing.